# Wait Install Process to move Foward -Powershell

Tags: powershell

I Have the following commands on a script's, my question is the script doesn't wait AWSCLI installation to set `aws configure 'parameters'`. How do I set a parameter to wait installation then call the following commands?

```
Start-Process -Wait -FilePath "${env:programfiles(x86)}\AWS\AWSCLIV2.msi" /quiet 

aws configure set default.region region-1
aws configure set aws_access_key_id 'key'
aws configure set aws_secret_access_key 'key'
```

Output:

```
aws : the term 'aws' is not recognize with a cmdlet name
```

Comment: You must have to specify the full path to aws.

Comment: @js2010 how do I specify the full path to load awscli module?

I used the following: Start-Process "${env:programfiles(x86)\aws\awscli.exe}" -ArgumentList "aws configure set default.region region-1" Doesn't work

Comment: I would do `$env:path += ';c:\program files (x86)\aws'; aws configure ...`

Comment: @js2010 Thank's a lot bro, it's worked.

The powershell process need to reboot to recognize awscli module, then a call a other batch script to make aws settings.